# drop all SQL tables that appear in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

I am attempting to develop a script to compare two databases to determine extra tables in one, then delete those tables. Here's my current script to locate the extraneous tables:

```
-- Any location where TARGET appears, replace TARGET with the database to be 
-- modified
-- Any location where MODEL appears, replace MODEL with the database being 
-- used as a model for comparison

select 'TARGET' as dbname, t1.table_name
from TARGET.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[tables] as t1
where table_name not in (select t2.table_name
from 
MODEL.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[tables] as t2  
)
```

That gives me the results I need, but now I need to fire out how to drop the tables. I'm afraid I'm utterly lost at this point. Wouldn't mind a way to declare variables instead of typing in the DBname repeatedly either, but not sure I can in this instance.

Comment: Use Dynamic SQL

Comment: Have you looked at the schema comparison tool in SSDT? Tools -> SQL Server -> New schema comparison. It'll write the script for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

select @sql += CONCAT('DROP TABLE ',QUOTENAME(t1.table_name,''''),';',CHAR(13))
from TARGET.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[tables] as t1
where table_name not in (select t2.table_name
                        from MODEL.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[tables] as t2);

SELECT @sql; -- debug
--EXEC(@sql);
```

## EDIT:

MySQL(may need some nitpicking):

```
SET @s = (select GROUP_CONCAT('DROP TABLE ''' + t1.table_name + ''';' SEPARATOR CHAR(13))
         from TARGET.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables as t1
         where table_name not in (select t2.table_name
                                  from MODEL.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables as t2));
SELECT @s; -- debug
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Just curious: can you convert this to MySQL? I'm asking for a friend...

Comment: @nicomp Sure, I will prepare code (difference will be prepared statement and GROUP_CONCAT);

Comment: That was close! I had to make a couple tweaks.

Change select CONCAT('DROP TABLE ',QUOTENAME(t1.table_name,'''')

CONCAT('DROP TABLE ',' ',QUOTENAME(t1.table_name,'')

or it throws an error. But you got me on the right track, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thought is to assign each result in your query a Row Number and place your results into a temp table. Use a while loop starting at 1 and loop through the maximum number you have within that temp table getting the name of the table that Row Number is assigned to each loop. Use that name to delete from the database.

```
select 'TARGET' as dbname, t1.table_name
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By t1.table_name) AS RowNumber
INTO #temp
from TARGET.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[tables] as t1
where table_name not in (select t2.table_name
                         from MODEL.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[tables] as t2)

DECLARE @counter INT = 1
DECLARE @maxNum INT
SELECT @maxNum = MAX(RowNumber) FROM #temp

While @counter <= @maxNum
   BEGIN
       DECLARE @tableName AS VARCHAR(MAX)
       SELECT @tableName = table_name FROM #temp WHERE RowNumber = @counter

       DELETE TABLE @tableName ' This may not be possible, but follow my lead

       @counter += 1
   END

DROP TABLE #temp
```

I am not sure if "DELETE TABLE @tableName" is a proper command but there is probably a very similar solution using what I have given you. I assume this is T-SQL..